# Error returning attribute of distinct nodes

Tags: xquery, basex

My xml file complies to the following DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT eprints (paper+)>
<!ELEMENT paper (eprintsid,userid,dir,datestamp,type,author+,title)>
<!ELEMENT eprintsid (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT userid (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT dir (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT datestamp (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT type (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>

<!ATTLIST author id CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

From this xml file I want to generate a list nodes of all distinct-values text nodes of author that match multiple id value, with the multiple id's as childnodes.

Therefore I tried using the following xquery:

```
let $doc := doc("eprints")
for $i in distinct-values($doc//author)
let $jn := $i/@id
where (count(distinct-values($jn)) > 1)
return <idByAuthor>{$jn}</idByAuthor>
```

Apparently XQuery does not allow me to traverse to the 'id' attribute node of `$i`, as I get the following error (from my xml database engine BaseX):
'context node required for '@id'; xs:untypedAtomic found.'.

Does anyone know why I can't reach the id attribute of `$i`?

Comment: Please, provide a small real XML document -- this will save time for anyone willing to have a look and understand your question. Please, edit the question and correct.

Answer (score 4):

[`distinct-values(...)`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_distinct-values.html) returns a set of atomic values (eg., numbers and strings), not XML nodes. You cannot do an axis step from these.

> From this xml file I want to generate a list nodes of all
>   distinct-values text nodes of author that match multiple id value,
>   with the multiple id's as childnodes.

That's not the problem you want to solve, that's the way you're trying to solve it. I guess you want to query all authors which provided more than one paper (or what ever they're author of). If I guessed wrong please write exactly what your query should do.

Try following this sketch (not valid XQuery yet):

```
for all authors $a
where count of all papers with author $a
return <idByAuthor>{$a/@id}</idByAuthor>
```

If you need more help with this query, please post some example XML snippet to work with, if you've got some code for the query this code and the desired output.

---

Code for clearified question:

```
for $author in distinct-values($doc//author)
let $ids := $doc//author[data()=$author]/@id/data()
where count($ids) > 1
return
  <author name="{ $author }">
  {
    for $id in $ids
    return <id>{ $id }</id>
  }
  </author>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on distinct-values(), this explains the error that I got. My ultimate goal is the following: - each author-node contains the author's name in it's textnode and it's id in a id attribute node. I want to know which author-names occur in the xml file with more than one distinct id, furthermore I also want to know which id values are used with this author-name (preferably in one query).

Comment: Please update you question with this information. I added some code to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

you might want to have a look at the `group by` expression, introduced with XQuery 3.0 (see [BaseX Doc](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_3.0#Group_By)).

Group by allows you to perform value based grouping, as such you could do something like in this [Gist, Group By Example](https://gist.github.com/2761801):

```
let $authors := 
<authors>
  <author id="a"><name>Foo</name>…whatever…</author>
  <author id="b"><name>Foo</name>…whatever…</author>
  <author id="a"><name>Foo</name>…whatever…</author>
  <author id="c"><name>Bar</name>…whatever…</author>
  <author id="d"><name>Bar</name>…whatever…</author>
  <author id="f"><name>FooBar</name>…whatever…</author>  
</authors> (: or use doc('eprints')//author :)
return
<distinct-names> {
  for $author in $authors//author
  group by $name := $author/name
  return
    if(count(distinct-values($author/@id)) > 1) then
      element {"author"}
              { 
                attribute {"name"} {$name},
                for $id in distinct-values($author/@id)
                return <id>{$id}</id>
              }
    else ()  
}</distinct-names>
```

I hope this helps, otherwise feel free to post a small snippet of your XML file.

Kind regards
Michael